# Validate share name

Tags: regex, powershell

How can i verify with powershell script if entered by user share name is c$ and nothing else? For example extract share name from \\hostname\c$

```
$sharename = Read-Host "Enter path"
if ( $sharename -eq "c$")
  {
    "execute script"
  }
else 
  {
    "ShareName must be c$"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-match` operator for regex, or `-like` for wildcards like so,

```
if ( $sharename -match "\\\\\w+\\c\$") {
    "execute script"
  }
```

The regex is built like so,

```
\\ -> \
\\ -> \
\w+ -> at least one word character
\\ -> \
c  -> letter 'c'
\$ -> dollar sign
```

Test cases

```
$sharename = '\\nomatter\c$'
$sharename -match "\\\\\w+\\c\$"
True


$sharename = '\\nomatter\C$'
$sharename -match "\\\\\w+\\c\$"
True


$sharename = '\\nomatter\d$'
$sharename -match "\\\\\w+\\c\$"
False

$sharename = '\\nomatter\cee$'
$sharename -match "\\\\\w+\\c\$"
False
```

Comment: You might want to add a `$` to the end of your pattern.  This will prevent any trailing characters.